# Redhawk crashing with Java error - Killed by signal 6, SIGABRT

Tags: java, eclipse, centos, centos6, redhawksdr

Centos 6.6

Redhawk 1.10

I can do a series of operations (program the IP of a USRP) in Redhawk that repeatedly cause the program to crash with the following error:

Source: java-1.7.0-openjdk

Problem: Process /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.71.x86_64/jre/bin/java was killed by signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Any idea on how to prevent this?

Also, I'm very new to Redhawk and Linux in general so please ELI5.

Answer (score 2):

Per someone way smarter than me on the subject:

> This is an issue that has just come up with the release of CentOS6.6
>   as it uses a newer version of gtk2 than CentOS6.5.  Eclipse detects
>   this and erroneously assumes it can use the cairo graphics API which
>   is either not available or not at the expected version.  It's actually
>   a bug within the Eclipse Version used by the v1.10 and v1.9 series
>   REDHAWK IDE.  Information about the issue can be found on this eclipse
>   forum.  Eclipse has since fixed the issue within it's latest code
>   base.
>
> The easiest fix for 1.10 and 1.9 users is to apply the fix mentioned
>   within the forum post.  Navigate to the directory which contains your
>   eclipse executable (REDHAWK IDE executable) and there should be a
>   configuration file called "eclipse.ini".  Add the following parameter
>   to the list of declared options:
>
> -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false
>
> This will disable the use of cairo graphics, which were not being used
>   in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this error happened because I was doing a remote debug on a process that wanted to spawn two separate JVM instances. One that executed a test runner and one that executed an actual test.
If you ran the program with with:

`export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7002"`

The instances both try to use port 7002 and the signal abort appears because 7002 is in use for the second instance.

Instead, you can use:

`export _JAVA_OPTIONS="agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7002"`

By setting suspend to yes, you prevent the instances from running simultaneously. Though you have to remember to connect the remote debugger twice to get the separate instances to execute.